# Laravel api routes not being authenicated

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I have Laravel passport installed on my dev environment. I noticed that no matter if I am logged in or not my api routes work. AN example of one of my routes is

```
Route::get('/users', function () {
    return factory('App\User', 10)->make();
});
```

Shouldn't it automatically be authenticated with the api middle ware since it is in the api routes?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('/users', function () {
       return factory('App\User', 10)->make();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

But for protect your routes not need to use an middleware declared after the route registered?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#protecting-routes

I.e:

```
Route::get('/users', function () {
return factory('App\User', 10)->make()})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Answer (score 0):

For using authenticated, you should modify your route as follows

```
Route::get('/users', function () {
    return factory('App\User', 10)->make();
})->middleware('auth');
```

Moreover, please revise file config/auth.php if you did not use a default User class

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\{your User class name}::class,
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the bindings in your `/app/Http/Kernel.php`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#via-middleware

Example:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
      ...
    ],
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        'auth:api',
    ],
];
```

And scopes if you want to use token scoping:

```
'scopes' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckScopes::class,
'scope' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyScope::class,
```

Full file example:

https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-passport/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php